# How can I separate a certain string that appears as substring in a list and put this as a key in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have text file with 4,000 lines, this file has a pattern, have a title machine, and after have a list of problems and solutions, example:

```
Balancim de corte hidráulico (a) ponte
Defect 01 – Máquina não liga
Botão de emergência acionado
Problema no pedal
Defeito 02 – O martelo não vai para os lados
Botão de emergência acionado
...
```

I want to read this and the output should be a dictionary like this:

```
machine_dict = {
                   'Balancim de corte hidráulico (a) ponte': { 'Defect 01 – Máquina não liga': ['Botão de emergência acionado', 'Problema no pedal'...], 'Defeito 02 – O martelo não vai para os lados': ['Botão de emergência acionado', ...]}
}
```

I have almost finished, but I can't separate the defects and the solution correctly. This is the code:

```
with open("Manual TPM/manual.txt") as manual:
    with open('Manual TPM/manual.txt') as manual:
        manual_tpm = manual.read()  

        maqs_defeito = [list.split('\n') for list in manual_tpm.split('\n\n') if list]

        maqs = {}
        defeitos=[]
        solucoes=[]

        for index, item in enumerate(maqs_defeito):
            maqs[item[0]] = {}
            if "Defeito" in item:
                defeitos.append([item,index])
            solucoes.append(item)

        for i in range(len(defeitos)):
            maqs[item[0]][defeitos[i][0]] = solucoes[defeitos[i][1]:]
        print(maqs)
```

Comment: Why use `open()` twice?

Comment: How does one determine the next machine from the prior solution?

Comment: I typed the first line and then I pasted the rest of the code, then it duplicated

Comment: Thats the problem, i dont know how to separate the machines

Comment: Is there only ever exactly one solution to each problem?

Comment: No, the number of solutions will depend on the machine.

Comment: With an arbitrary number of solutions and no way to landmark the beginning of a new device, I fear you might by kind of out of luck.

Comment: That's what I feared

Comment: Is there any chance that you can build/acquire a list of the valid device names to help disambiguate the name of a device from the text of a solution?

Comment: How it can help with the defects and solutions?

Comment: defects start with a keyword and are easy to pick out. Then you have one or more solutions to that defect until you read a line with the defect keyword signaling a new defect and arbitrarily many solutions. The real problem as I see it is to detect when the last solution for the last defect turns into the next device.

Comment: Yes, the only way will be edit the txt file, putting the name of the machine in before every defects

Comment: maybe easier to add a newline before each existing machine row

Comment: Its already have, but dont solve the solution. The problem is separate the defects and the solutions

Comment: I made it. But you can help with one more thing? The method "With open" don't recognize the "-" caracter neigther acentuation like "é".  How can I fix it?

Comment: encoding="utf-8h

Answer (score 1):

I had to insert the name of the machine before every problem in the txt file, like this:

```
Balancim de corte hidraulico (a) ponte
Defeito 01 - Maquina nao liga
Botao de emergencia acionado

Balancim de corte hidraulico (a) ponte
Defeito 02 - O martelo nao vai para os lados
Botao de emergencia acionado

Balancim de Corte hidraulico Braco (Tecnomaq)
Defeito 01 - O martelo sobe e desce lento
Filtro de óleo entupido

Balancim de Corte hidraulico Braco (Tecnomaq)
Defeito 02 - O martelo sobe todo e aumenta o ruido do balancim
Operador regulou muito alto o martelo
```

The code to separete:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import pandas as pd

with open('manual.txt') as manual:
    manual_tpm = manual.read()  

    maqs_defeito = [list.split('\n') for list in 
    manual_tpm.split('\n\n') if list]

    maqs_problem_solution = {}
    for list_maquina in maqs_defeito:
        maqs_problem_solution[list_maquina[0]] = {}
        
    for posicao, list_maquina in enumerate(maqs_defeito):
        maqs_problem_solution[list_maquina[0]][list_maquina[1]] = list_maquina[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

path = "/path/to/input.txt"

with open(path) as manual:
    manual = manual.read().split('\n')
    output = {}
    i = 0
    while i < len(manual)-1:
        # if the start of the next line matches with "Defect 01" or "Defeito 01", we've found a new item
        if re.match(r"^Def.*? 01", manual[i+1]):
            if i > 0: # for every line except the first, add the item and its dictionary to the output dict
                output[item_name] = item_dict
            item_name = manual[i]
            item_dict = {}

        # if the start of the current line is "Def", we've found a new defect
        elif manual[i][0:3] == 'Def':
            if not re.match(r"^Def.*? 01", manual[i]): # for every defect except the first, add the defect and its solutions to the item dictionary
                item_dict[defect] = solutions
            defect = manual[i][12:]
            solutions = []
        
        # otherwise, it's just another solution
        else:
            solutions.append(manual[i])
        i += 1

    # we need to do this for the last one, because re.match(r"^Def.*? 01", manual[i+1]) causes it to fail on the last index 
    solutions.append(manual[i])
    item_dict[defect] = solutions
    output[item_name] = item_dict
```

Output:

```
{'Balancim de corte hidráulico (a) ponte': {'Máquina não liga': ['Botão de emergência acionado', 'Problema no pedal']}, 'Balancim de Corte hidraulico Braco (Tecnomaq)': {' O martelo sobe e desce lento': ['Filtro de óleo entupido'], ' O martelo sobe todo e aumenta o ruido do balancim': ['Operador regulou muito alto o martelo']}}
```

Data:

```
Balancim de corte hidráulico (a) ponte
Defect 01 – Máquina não liga
Botão de emergência acionado
Problema no pedal
Defeito 02 – O martelo não vai para os lados
Botão de emergência acionado
Balancim de Corte hidraulico Braco (Tecnomaq)
Defeito 01 - O martelo sobe e desce lento
Filtro de óleo entupido
Defeito 02 - O martelo sobe todo e aumenta o ruido do balancim
Operador regulou muito alto o martelo
```

Comment: Hi @Mark I reach out to you true this commend Sorry for doing this :e But can you help me again? The open Question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634338/histogram-unequal-number-on-the-y-axis There Is an answer but I dont get it :e