# Histogram unequal number on the Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram in a Matplotlib subplot. I have the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

def plot_Diff(data):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax =fig.add_subplot(423)  
    x= dfe['O18ad']
    bins=[-20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
    old_yticks = ax.get_yticks()
    bin_counts, _, bars = plt.hist(x, bins,  alpha=0.65, label='old', edgecolor='black', color='lightgrey')
    new_ticks = old_yticks[old_yticks < bin_counts.max()]
    new_ticks = np.append(new_ticks, bin_counts.max())
    ax.set_yticks(new_ticks)

plt.show()
```

my data:

```
0        -4.268475
1        -4.265793
2        -4.263120
3        -4.260457
4        -4.257803
            ...
359995   -7.813345
359996   -7.821394
359997   -7.773479
359998   -7.807605
359999   -7.797769
```

The result looks like this
[image]

How can I get the maximum value to be displayed automatically on the Y axis?

When I use the answer from it looks like this! I have also adapted the code accordingly

-
[image]

Comment: As a side note: `plt.ylim= (-500, 500)` overwrites the `plt.ylim` function, making it unreachable.  You probably want `plt.ylim(-500, 500)` instead, although that doesn't make sense for your data. As you already explicitly created an `ax`, staying with the object-oriented interface would prefer `ax.hist(...)` and `ax.set_ylim(...)` instead of the `plt` functions.

Comment: If you catch the return values of the histogram, i.e. `vals, _bins, _rects = ax.hist(x, ....)`, you can use `max(vals)` to add a y-tick. `ax.set_yticks(list(ax.get_yticks()) + [max(vals)])`.

Comment: @JohanC I`m quite new to coding, where should i write this? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example below I start by removing the existing ticks that are close to or more than the new max value. Then I add in the desired max tick value. If we don't remove some of the existing ticks, they're close enough to overlap with the new one and make the labelling unclear.

[image]

With some optional extra labelling and aesthetics:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

#Test data
np.random.seed(0)
dfe = pd.DataFrame({'O18ad': np.random.randn(600_000) * 4 - 10})

#Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot()  

x = dfe['O18ad']

# bins=[-20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
# A more compact way of defining the bins
bins = np.arange(-20, 2)

bin_counts, _, bars = plt.hist(x, bins,  alpha=0.65, label='old', edgecolor='black', color='lightgrey')

new_max_tick = bin_counts.max()
old_yticks = ax.get_yticks()
#Drop everything > new_max_tick
#Also, drop the second-to-last tick to ensure clearance
new_ticks = old_yticks[old_yticks < new_max_tick][:-1]

#Insert new tick    
new_ticks = np.append(new_ticks, new_max_tick)
ax.set_yticks(new_ticks)
```

Adding bar labels and removing some spines:

```
#You could also label the bars
# I've customised it but you could just use ax.bar_label(bars)
ax.bar_label(
    bars,
    fontsize=8, color='tab:red', rotation=90,
    label_type='edge', padding=5, fmt=lambda v: int(round(v, -2))
)

#Remove the top and right spines for aesthetics
[ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ('top', 'right')]

plt.show()
```

---

Adapting the OP's `plot_Diff()` function:

```
#Test data
np.random.seed(0)
dfe = pd.DataFrame({'O18ad': np.random.randn(600_000) * 4 - 10})


def plot_Diff(data, manual_ticks=None, extra_formatting=True):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(423)
    
    x = dfe['O18ad']
    bins=[-20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
    bin_counts, _, bars = plt.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.65, label='old', edgecolor='black', color='lightgrey')
    
    new_max_tick = bin_counts.max()
    
    if manual_ticks is None:
        old_yticks = ax.get_yticks()
        #Drop everything > new_max_tick
        #Also, drop the second-to-last tick to ensure clearance
        new_ticks = old_yticks[old_yticks < new_max_tick][:-1]

        #Insert new tick    
        new_ticks = np.append(new_ticks, new_max_tick)
    else:
        new_ticks = np.append(manual_ticks, new_max_tick)
        
    ax.set_yticks(new_ticks)

    if extra_formatting:
        #Label axes
        ax.set_ylabel('counts')
        ax.set_xlabel('bin edge')
        ax.set_title(f'Histogram of {x.name}\n\n')
        
        #You could also label the bars
        # I've customised it but you could just use ax.bar_label(bars)
        ax.bar_label(
            bars,
            fontsize=8, color='tab:red', rotation=90,
            label_type='edge', padding=5, fmt=lambda v: int(round(v, -2))
        )

        #Remove the top and right spines for aesthetics
        [ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ('top', 'right')]

#Basic usage:
plot_Diff(dfe)
plt.show()

#If you want to set some ticks:
plot_Diff(dfe, manual_ticks=[0, 30_000])
plt.show()

#If you don't want extra formatting:
plot_Diff(dfe, extra_formatting=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer! However I don´t get it completly :D Can you help me and have a look whats wrong whith my data :D

Comment: No worries. I have updated my answer to show how I wrapped the code in your original function. If it still doesn't work please consider supplying some sample data.

Comment: let me try this and then I will come back to you if its works :D

Comment: Okay I tested it: when I use ''' ax.bar_label(bars,fontsize=8, color='tab:red', rotation=90, label_type='edge', padding=5, fmt=lambda v: int(round(v, -2)))   ''' I get the error ''' TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'function' and 'float'''

Comment: Does removing the part `fmt=lambda v: int(round(v, -2))` resolve that error?

Comment: Ah yes it works :D but I only want the first Pic you posted, wait I update my code :D

Comment: Glad it's working. Changing `extra_formatting=True` to `extra_formatting=False` will skip all the extra formatting. Alternatively, you can manually delete whatever extra parts you don't want.

Comment: As you see in my updated code I didn´t consider the extra_formating however the problem that the Numbers on my y achsis are like in the 2 pic i posted remain :C

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256216/discussion-between-weiss-and-user3128).

Comment: @Weiss do you understand it now?

Comment: @Mark yes thank you very much :D

Comment: @user3128 Hi I have an aditional question? is there a way only to display the 0, 30000 und 61538 tick in the fig I posted?

Comment: @Weiss Yes, I have changed the code to include a `manual_ticks=` option. You can use `plot_Diff(dfe, manual_ticks=[0, 30_000])`, and it will add those in to the max tick.

Comment: @user3128 This looks quite complicated, you mean the if when option or? can you impliment this more easyly?

Comment: Yes the `if...else` part handles the manual ticks. Would you prefer the extra ticks to be handled *outside* of the function rather than adding it inside the function?

Comment: Okay I try to aply this if else part and let you know :D

Comment: Ok Thanks again it works perfectly

Comment: No worries, glad it's working.

Comment: @user3128 I do have another question? When you look at my Histos you see the X axis Values didn`t alinght with the outer lines! How can I fix this? all the best :D

Comment: Adding these helps a bit: `plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), ha='center')` and
`ax.tick_params(bottom=False)`. But if it's not as desired I think it's worth asking as a new question.